# Run process continuously pass objects with current time to event?

Tags: c#

I have a list of transactions in a list with each transaction having a specific date/time

I need to implement something that is always running then checks my list and fires off a method given each transaction found for the current time

What is the best approach for this?

For example

Transaction 1 11:22:11
Transaction 2 11:22:55

At 11:22:11 I need to fire off a method giving the method Transaction 1 
At 11:22:55 I need to fire off a method giving the method Transaction 2

I have seen people mention quartz but my requirement doesnt really fit into a scheduler/job scenario and I need this to be running within my application

I am using C#

Paul

Comment: What if your program IS NOT running at the given time?

Comment: have you tried creating a thread which raises an event when your "specific time" time occurs?

Comment: Are you sure this should be done within your app? Think about task scheduler or writing a service

Comment: The program will be running.  I am basically replaying transactions.  So all transactions for specific time range yesterday will be changed to today then this process will pick up the transactions and replay them. I'm not sure about the thread/event approach as that would create loads of threads

Comment: There are no multiple thread only single thread which will raise event at specific time which will be handled by method you're trying to call

Comment: `I'm not sure about the thread/event approach as that would create loads of threads` The point is to have **one** thread whose job it is to repeatedly check the time and fire the needed requests. You don't need to create _many_ threads.

Comment: This is not a production system, it just a simple application for replaying I dont want to add the complexity of services etc

Comment: What is the goal of replaying the events? I'd think that clicking buttons yourself would be considerably easier and functionally equivalent for your intentions. Why does it need to be scheduled? Are you trying to reproduce race conditions?

Comment: I am trying to replay actions that occurred yesterday in real time there can be a lot of transactions so clicking buttons is def not an option.  If I go down the thread route do I just have a while loop that never ends that constantly checks the time?

Comment: @Paul whats the problem in that

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for List and then call your method from extension method.

That way you'll have the current object of the transaction and at the time of adding it.

```
public static class MyExtensions 
{
    public static void AddWithFire<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
    {
         list.Add(item);
         // Add Your method call with item object
         // YourMethod(item);
    }
}
```

**Update: Let say you want to play with any property of your object**

```
public static class MyExtensions 
{
    public static void AddWithFire<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
    {
         list.Add(item);

         if(item is Transaction)
         {
            // Call Your method that takes DateTime
            YourMethod(((Transaction)item).TransactionDate);
         }
    }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public DateTime TransactionDate {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: My transaction has a property inside TransactionDateTime not too sure how this approach fits in?

Comment: Thanks my task here is more to only call my method at the specific time for the object

Comment: Yeah @Paul the way I added a check for date time any way you like, similarily I have added for transaction object.

Comment: My list already has transactions in it.  The caller will be creating this list and i need something that looks at this list all the time, running the method for each transaction 1 by 1 that has the current date/time

Comment: @Paul replace that caller with extension methods code. that'll more easy and reliable approach to use for this. obviously, if you have access to the list for checking it you must have access to code which adds transaction in the list. so just replace that add call and you're done